# Ubuntu 12.04 pacemaker cluster fails to load Apache after adding ioncube zend loader to php.ini

Tags: php, apache, cluster-computing, pacemaker

I have configured a cluster and it runs properly unless I add a zend extension to the php.ini file.
In my test, I have the failover server shut down so that I am only dealing with a single server.
I am running Ubuntu 12.04, corosync 1.4.2 and drbd 8.4.3
Here's my relevant crm config:

```
primitive apache2 ocf:heartbeat:apache \
        params configfile="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" httpd="/usr/sbin/apache2" \
        operations $id="apache2-operations" \
        op monitor interval="15s" \
        op start interval="0" timeout="240s" \
        op stop interval="0" timeout="240s" \
        meta target-role="started"
```

My php.ini is the stock one that installs with apt-get
In this case, it works fine.

But when I add a zend load to the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:

```
zend_extension = /var/www/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
```

I can run service apache restart and the website comes up
But if I try to start it from crm, it fails with the following logs:

```
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: WARN: Managed apache2:start process 2675 exited with return code 1.
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: operation start[31] on apache2 for client 1051: pid 2675 exited with return code 1
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 crmd: [1051]: info: process_lrm_event: LRM operation apache2_start_0 (call=31, rc=1, cib-update=42, confirmed=true) unknown error
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 attrd: [1049]: notice: attrd_ais_dispatch: Update relayed from lzc2
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 attrd: [1049]: notice: attrd_trigger_update: Sending flush op to all hosts for: fail-count-apache2 (INFINITY)
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 attrd: [1049]: notice: attrd_perform_update: Sent update 53: fail-count-apache2=INFINITY
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 attrd: [1049]: notice: attrd_ais_dispatch: Update relayed from lzc2
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 attrd: [1049]: notice: attrd_trigger_update: Sending flush op to all hosts for: last-failure-apache2 (1397790983)
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 attrd: [1049]: notice: attrd_perform_update: Sent update 55: last-failure-apache2=1397790983
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 crmd: [1051]: info: do_lrm_rsc_op: Performing key=6:102:0:c4a37f0f-2071-433e-83a3-50fb5d9e0ad2 op=apache2_stop_0 )
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: rsc:apache2 stop[32] (pid 2782)
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 apache[2782]: INFO: apache is not running.
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: Managed apache2:stop process 2782 exited with return code 0.
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: operation stop[32] on apache2 for client 1051: pid 2782 exited with return code 0
    Apr 17 23:16:23 lzc1 crmd: [1051]: info: process_lrm_event: LRM operation apache2_stop_0 (call=32, rc=0, cib-update=43, confirmed=true) ok
    Apr 17 23:16:24 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: operation monitor[22] on res_IPaddr2_ClusterIP for client 1051: pid 2847 exited with return code 0
```

If I comment out the zend line from /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
;zend_extension = /var/www/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
```

Then start the server, it works. Here are the logs for when it works:

```
Apr 17 23:20:10 lzc1 crmd: [1051]: info: do_lrm_rsc_op: Performing key=76:107:0:c4a37f0f-2071-433e-83a3-50fb5d9e0ad2 op=apache2_start_0 )
Apr 17 23:20:10 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: rsc:apache2 start[37] (pid 12579)
Apr 17 23:20:10 lzc1 cib: [1047]: info: Managed write_cib_contents process 12578 exited with return code 0.
Apr 17 23:20:10 lzc1 apache[12579]: INFO: apache not running
Apr 17 23:20:10 lzc1 apache[12579]: INFO: waiting for apache /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to come up
Apr 17 23:20:11 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: Managed apache2:start process 12579 exited with return code 0.
Apr 17 23:20:11 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: operation start[37] on apache2 for client 1051: pid 12579 exited with return code 0
Apr 17 23:20:11 lzc1 crmd: [1051]: info: process_lrm_event: LRM operation apache2_start_0 (call=37, rc=0, cib-update=53, confirmed=true) ok
Apr 17 23:20:11 lzc1 crmd: [1051]: info: do_lrm_rsc_op: Performing key=77:107:0:c4a37f0f-2071-433e-83a3-50fb5d9e0ad2 op=apache2_monitor_15000 )
Apr 17 23:20:11 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: rsc:apache2 monitor[38] (pid 12673)
Apr 17 23:20:11 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: Managed apache2:monitor process 12673 exited with return code 0.
Apr 17 23:20:11 lzc1 lrmd: [1048]: info: operation monitor[38] on apache2 for client 1051: pid 12673 exited with return code 0
Apr 17 23:20:11 lzc1 crmd: [1051]: info: process_lrm_event: LRM operation apache2_monitor_15000 (call=38, rc=0, cib-update=54, confirmed=false) ok
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but this fixed it. 
From the ssh console:

```
export OCF_ROOT=/usr/lib/ocf
export OCF_RESKEY_configfile="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" httpd="/usr/sbin/apache2" statusurl="http://127.0.0.1/server-status" envfiles="/etc/apache2/envvars"
/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/apache start
/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/apache stop
crm resource manage apache2
```

Maybe it wasn't "managed" before?